# Android - associate a user to some list item

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm developing an android application which allows different users to login and see a list of favourite songs.
Each user has its list of songs, and a song is an instance of the corresponding `class Song`, with some attributes (`singer`, `year`, `title`...). The `MainActivity` contains the form for the login, so the user has to set its `Name` and `Password`. After login, a second activity is started, and it contains the `ListView` with the user's favourite songs.

How can i associate a single user to its corresponding song's list?
I thinked to use a database to store the songs, but then?

Comment: Look at this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: i know how to store data...my question is: do i have to store all the information, including user's name and password in the same db, and then do a query with user's credentials to find all the songs related to him?

Comment: I think you should do something like that, do you need to access data, you have created on one device, also on other devices?

Comment: also on other devices!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Parse](https://www.parse.com) it's very easy to use and let you focus on your android App, instead of spending much time writing and configuring a server-side application.

You need also to implement on your android application a service to handle json ( or xml, it's your choice ). This is an awesome library to handle json [JSONP](https://jsonp.java.net/).

Look also to this link for an overview on [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)services.

For example (getting user info):

1. You need an info on userA.
2. You format a json with the right info.
3. Start an http request to your server. It will answer you with another json containing some info.
4. Parse this json recieved and use the data in your app.

I hope I made myself clear.